# Applying custom ImageMagick (GraphicsMagick) envelope distortion to text

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, graphicsmagick

I want to generate text like this using ImageMagick:

[image: Warped text]

I have the [font](http://www.dafont.com/jersey-letters.font) as a TTF file and know how to generate an image with just the undistorted text. What I'm having trouble with is applying the distortion.

The "envelope" I want to use looks like this:

[image: Envelope]

I've been reading over [ImageMagick's examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/) on distortions but can't seem to figure out the right command.

Please note, this is not an arc.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post the images you have obtained in your attempts?

Answer (score 2):

This is a quite complex task: ImageMagick has some built-in distortion effects, but no one resembles the one you need.

To achieve your goal you can try to define a custom distortion: for example using image maps (in particular absolute distortion lookup maps, more info [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/mapping/#distortion_maps)).

Basically you create a black/white gradient image (the map) that define how a particular effect should be applied to every single pixel of the image.

The tricky part is correctly generating image map: you can do it manually or using ImageMagick.

For example this command taken from ImageMagick docs creates a spherical distortion map:

```
  convert -size 100x100 xc:  -channel R \
          -fx 'yy=(j+.5)/h-.5; (i/w-.5)/(sqrt(1-4*yy^2))+.5' \
          -separate  +channel     sphere_lut.png
```

this is the resulting image:

[image: spherical distortion map]

once you've created your distortion map you can apply it to your image for example with:

```
convert input.png lut_mask.png -fx 'p{ v*w, j }' output.png
```